# laravel - Cors middleware causing response error when using Header()

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.6 and this Middleware to allow Ionic app call my API's

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;

class Cors
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With, X-XSRF-TOKEN');
    }
}
```

So this is causing error for two requests where I'm forcing file download.

```
Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse::header()
```

My request 1

```
return Excel::download(new \App\Exports\FleetExport($fleetId), 'debts.xlsx');
```

My request 2

```
return \Response::download($file_path,
                           $file_name,
                           array('Content-Type: application/octet-stream','Content-Length: '. filesize($file_path))
                           )->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
```

Disabling this middleware makes my requests works fine.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to adjust your middleware to set the headers on the header bag of the Response directly:

```
$response = $next($request);

$response->headers->add([
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
     ...
]);

return $response;
```

All the responses that come through should extend from the base Symfony Response which has a public `$headers` property that is a `HeaderBag`. So this should work for all the responses.